# How to subtract previous value in a column with calculation of other column on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement for a table as shown below. As you can see `mgt_year`,`tot_dflt_mgt` and `to_accum_mgt` columns. In year column where its **2016** the value is **20** and accum value is **600**. What I want is that when I do

```
(to_accum_mgt - tot_dflt_mgt)
```

I want this calculated result in previous row as shown in the table below. Then this calculated result i.e. **580** is used for subtracting **9** like **(580 - 9)** for year 2015 and so on for all trailing years. I have done this in excel and also in Oracle thanks to `@mathguy`, but how to achieve this result in SQL server.  I have tried to use this **SQL server** but its not working.

Please forgive My bad English and noob formatting.

My table t:

```
line_seg    MGT_YEAR TOT_DFLT_MGT TOT_ACCUM_MGT
---------   -------- ------------ ------------
   A           2013           10   
   A           2014           15   
   A           2015            9   
   A           2016           20          600
   B           2013           10   
   B           2014           15   
   B           2015            8   
   B           2016           20          500
```

Oracle Solution:

```
select mgt_year, tot_dflt_mgt,
       max(tot_accum_mgt) over () - 
         nvl( sum(tot_dflt_mgt) over 
                   (order by mgt_year 
                          rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
            , 0 ) as tot_accum_mgt
from t;
```

but I am unable use this in `SQL Server`.

required output

```
line_seg    MGT_YEAR TOT_DFLT_MGT TOT_ACCUM_MGT
---------   -------- ------------ ------------
   A           2013           10          556
   A           2014           15          471 
   A           2015            9          580
   A           2016           20          600
   B           2013           12          457
   B           2014           15          472
   B           2015            8          480
   B           2016           20          500
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,
(sum(TOT_ACCUM_MGT) over()) -
(sum(TOT_DFLT_MGT ) over (order by TOT_DFLT_MGT )) as somecolname
from
table
```

Comment: Thank you @TheGameiswar . But you are subtracting TOT_ACCUM_MGT - TOT_accum_mgt. And I tried this also but not working.

Comment: Hello @TheGameiswar. I have edited the question. Kindly check it again may be it will give you better idea what i am looking for. And Thank again for the solution you gave me but its not working in SQL server.

Comment: please explain your output

Comment: As you can see in the table above the I need to do this `(to_accum_mgt - tot_dflt_mgt)` in trailing . The output of this will go in previous row of `tot_accum_mgt` and it will be used to subtract the value of `tot_dflt_mgt` of that row and vice versa, until the `line_seg` window as shown in the Table of Output.

Answer (score 0):

Put Row_number() and self join it with the previous row on (a.ID = b.ID) and (a.row_num = b.row_num - 1)
OR
You can use lag() function

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query. I assumed that you are using 2012+ version of SQL Server. If not, please change the FIRST_VALUE to SUM -

```
SELECT t1.line_seg, t1.mgt_year, t1.[tot_dflt_mgt]
, FIRST_VALUE(t1.tot_accum_mgt) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.[line_seg] ORDER BY t1.mgt_year DESC)
- ISNULL(SUM(t2.[tot_dflt_mgt]) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.[line_seg] ORDER BY t2.mgt_year DESC), 0) AS tot_accum_mgt
FROM [dbo].[t] AS t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[t] AS t2 ON (t2.line_seg = t1.line_seg AND t2.mgt_year = t1.mgt_year + 1)
ORDER BY t1.line_seg, t1.mgt_year ASC;
```

To do this first I have to imagine the table as sorted by the descending order of date -

```
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  line_seg  | mgt_year | tot_dflt_mgt | tot_accum_mgt |
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| A          |     2016 |           20 | 600           |
| A          |     2015 |            9 | NULL          |
| A          |     2014 |           15 | NULL          |
| A          |     2013 |           10 | NULL          |
| B          |     2016 |           20 | 500           |
| B          |     2015 |            8 | NULL          |
| B          |     2014 |           15 | NULL          |
| B          |     2013 |           12 | NULL          |
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Then all I have to do is to subtract the PREVIOUS running total of **tot_dflt_mgt** from the latest year's **tot_accum_mgt**. This is equivalent to subtract the previous **tot_dflt_mgt** from the current **computed** value of  **tot_accum_mgt** To use the previous year's fields LEFT JOIN is used to self join the table. Resulting in the following table  -

```
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  line_seg  | mgt_year | tot_dflt_mgt | tot_accum_mgt |  line_seg  | mgt_year | tot_dflt_mgt | tot_accum_mgt |
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| A          |     2013 |           10 | NULL          | A          | 2014     | 15           | NULL          |
| A          |     2014 |           15 | NULL          | A          | 2015     | 9            | NULL          |
| A          |     2015 |            9 | NULL          | A          | 2016     | 20           | 600           |
| A          |     2016 |           20 | 600           | NULL       | NULL     | NULL         | NULL          |
| B          |     2013 |           12 | NULL          | B          | 2014     | 15           | NULL          |
| B          |     2014 |           15 | NULL          | B          | 2015     | 8            | NULL          |
| B          |     2015 |            8 | NULL          | B          | 2016     | 20           | 500           |
| B          |     2016 |           20 | 500           | NULL       | NULL     | NULL         | NULL          |
+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

The **AND t2.mgt_year = t1.mgt_year + 1** filter in the LEFT join clause does the trick of getting previous rows value. Now all I had to do is to calculate the running total on this previous rows (t2). Also as, subtracting **NULL** from anything will result in **NULL**. So **ISNULL** replaces any **NULL** with zeros.

```
ISNULL(SUM(t2.[tot_dflt_mgt]) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.[line_seg] ORDER BY t2.mgt_year DESC), 0) AS tot_accum_mgt
```

Now, as we have the previous running total of tot_dflt_mgt, all we have to do is to delete the latest (largest **mgt_year**) **tot_accum_mgt**. We get that by using **FIRST_VALUE** function. SUM could also be used instead I guess.

```
FIRST_VALUE(t1.tot_accum_mgt) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.[line_seg] ORDER BY t1.mgt_year DESC)
```

Comment: Thank you `@shiblu` will try this and 'll let you know.